# Looping through workbook and deleting VeryHidden worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

One of the modules in a larger project is creating redundant veryHidden sheets. I am attempting to loop through every worksheet in the workbook and delete sheets that are marked as veryHidden. I've used almost identical code in other projects and it has worked so I am unsure why it is not working in this situation. Here is what I've tried:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        sheet.Delete
    End If
Next sheet
```

I've also tried that same code using:

```
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook
```

And I've also tried:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheetCount As Integer
For i = 1 To sheetCount
    If Worksheets(i).Visible = xlVeryHidden Then
        Worksheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

And also:

```
For i = sheetCount To 3 Step -1
    If Worksheets(i).Visible = xlVeryHidden Then
        Worksheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

In all attempts `Application.DisplayAlerts` is changed to `False` before running and changed to `True` after running. Results in run-time error 1004.

Comment: I suggest to make it visible, after identifying as hidden and then delete.I hope this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unhide the sheet before deleting it, it should work.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        sheet.visible = xlSheetVisible
        sheet.Delete
    End If
Next sheet
```