# How to delete sheets except for certain sheets in the VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, but excel always crashes when I run it. I don't receive an error code or anything. Excel just closes out.

```
Sub DeleteSheets()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Overview" And xWs.Name <> "Models-Features" And xWs.Name <> "Formulas" And xWs.Name <> "Original Features" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That's weird because the code looks good and I cannot reproduce the issue. Also Excel crashing means there is an error in Excel or in your file (not in your code). Please go through the code step by step using F8 and tell us in which line your Excel crashes. • Before, make sure you update to the latest build version and restart your computer (just in case). • Note that `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that is on top (has focus). Focus can easily change by a mouse click. You might want to use `ThisWorkbook` instead which is the workbook the code is written in.

Comment: Is there at least one sheet that has one of those names? VBA should throw an error when you try to delete the last one, but I'm wondering if there's some version-specific bug that's allowing it to happen.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Excel crashes at xWs.Delete after it cycles through my sheet names the line before.

Comment: @Prattso test if this occurs with other files on your computer too. So we know if it is your computer (your Excel) or your specific file. Your code runs fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your code is deleting all sheets causing the error, even if one is labeled "Overview".  I cleaned this up using `Select`, which now does not delete the appropriate named sheets:

```
Sub DeleteSheets()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheets.Count = 1 Then Exit For
        Select Case xWs.Name
            Case "Overview"
            Case "Models-Features"
            Case "Formulas"
            Case "Original Features"
            Case Else
                xWs.Delete
        End Select
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Edit1:  Added check for `Sheets.Count` which will prevent the error caused by deleting the last sheet in the workbook.

Edit2:  Added additional `application` constraints

Comment: Excel is still crashing for me once it runs xWs.Delete. My thought is the amount of sheets that are to be deleted is too many. Number of sheets vary on this workbook, but around 15 sheets should be deleted from the macro.

Comment: @Prattso Have you verified the names of your sheets?  I only have the error on the `xWs.Delete` line when I had deleted all sheets.

Comment: Yes, I have even gone through and changed them to other names as well to see if there were mistakes.

Comment: @Prattso I updated with a check which prevents deleting the last sheet in the workbook.  An additional thought would be an issue with deleting a protected sheet; do you have any protected sheets?

Comment: Possibly useful [...Deleting veryhidden worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207522/looping-through-workbook-and-deleting-veryhidden-worksheets)?

Comment: Touching on your above point, the number of sheets being removed should be irrelevant.  I ran this over a workbook housing over 100 sheets and it was near instantaneous.

Comment: Unfortunately, the check did not work. I do not have any protected sheet on the workbook. I have the 4 constant sheets that I don't want deleted, then I have another macro that copies sheets over from another workbook into this one.

Comment: @Prattso Are there any `Change` events going on?  If you `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the start of the code, I wonder if that wouldn't prevent the crashing...

Comment: @Cyril Excel crashing always means the error is in Excel itself or in a corrupt Excel file. Otherwise it would throw an exception in VBA. So deleting the last sheet throws an error and therefore cannot be the issue.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I added both of those and it worked!

Comment: @Prattso  updated the post to include those lines (and turning them back on), as the last assumption was a dependency in your workbook caused by a calculation or event was causing the crash when a specific sheet is deleted

Comment: @Prattso Well, I would definitely investigate the root cause of that error, because that means something is probably wrong with your file if that causes Excel to crash. Solving the symptoms might look handsome at the moment but bites you in the a… later :/